# How to set breakpoint before window loads?

Tags: debugging, extjs, breakpoints

How can I set a break point in a browser at line before form loads. I would like to debug extjs application in a browser, but every time I start the application breakpoints reset, so I can only set them after application has been loaded. For example, I would like to set breakpoint in launch function before my login dialog loads, as show in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look in api doc for appropriate event, in your case maybe the 'beforerender' and write there "debugger;"
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger
something like

```
Ext.widget('login-dialog', {
    listeners: {
        beforerender: function() {
            debugger;
        }
    }
});
```